# appendToLi() function requiring a return?

Tags: javascript

Quick question... what is the reason that I need to return the 'element' variable when using the appendToLi? If I remove the line, the code will not add anything to the list. It's confusing to me because the appendToLi function calls are not returning the element to anything.

For example, I would understand if it looked like this...

```
let element = appendToLi(property, value, text);
```

But that is not the case. I have...

```
appendToLi(property, value, text);
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  

  //Targets the unordered list element
  const list = document.getElementById("myUL");
  //Targets the children of the unordered list
  const li = list.children;

  //Targets the form element.
  const form = document.getElementById("registrar");

  //Function declaration (Begins process of creating list item)
  function createListItem(text){
    //Creates the list item
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    //Function delcaration (creates an element and returns element)
    function createElement(elementName, property, value) {
      const element = document.createElement(elementName);
      element[property] = value;
      return element;
    }

    //Function declaration (Adds the created element to the list)
    function appendToLi(elementName, property, value){
      const element = createElement(elementName, property, value);
      li.appendChild(element);
      return element;
    }

      //Appends all children to the list item.
      appendToLi('span', 'textContent', text);
      appendToLi('label', 'textContent', 'Completed')
        .appendChild(createElement('input', 'type', 'checkbox'));
      appendToLi('button', 'textContent', 'remove');
      appendToLi('button', 'textContent', 'edit');

      /*Returns the list item and it's children to what has called the
      createListItem function*/
      return li;
  }

    //Event listener (listens for click on submit button/enter press)
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      //Targets the input element.
      const input = document.querySelector('input');

      //If the user has not entered any text in the  input field, alerts.
      if(input.value === '') {
        alert('Please enter an item!');

      //Otherise begins the process of creating the list item.
      } else {

        //Holds the user text input.
        const text = input.value;

        /*Calls the createListItem function which will begin the process
          through various other functions.*/
        const listItem = createListItem(text);
        list.appendChild(listItem);
        input.value = '';
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
appendToLi('label', 'textContent', 'Completed')
  .appendChild(createElement('input', 'type', 'checkbox'));
```

... throws an error and interrupts script execution if `appendToLi()` doesn't return the element.

The above lines of code are equivalent to this:

```
var element = appendToLi('label', 'textContent', 'Completed');
element.appendChild(createElement('input', 'type', 'checkbox'));
```

Here, it's easier to see what happens when `appendToLi()` doesn't return anything: `element` becomes `undefined` and you then try to invoke a method called `appendChild` on it which throws an error since `undefined` doesn't have any methods or properties.

Comment: Is this because without returning anything.... the function never ends? I'm new to JS so bare with me ;P

Comment: @CollinDeSoto It's because you invoke a method called `appendChild` on whatever gets returned by `appendToLi()`. If `appendToLi()` doesn't return anything you're trying invoke `appendChild()` on `undefined` which throws an error which in turn causes your script to stop at that point. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you are creating elements when form is submitted. There is guess what I can make as I don't know why you are doing what. In the code section below:

```
//Function declaration (Adds the created element to the list)
function appendToLi(elementName, property, value){
  const element = createElement(elementName, property, value);
  li.appendChild(element);
  return element;
}
  //Creates the list item
  const li = document.createElement('li');

  //Appends all children to the list item.
  appendToLi('span', 'textContent', text);
```

Here you created the li after you have declared the function **appendToLi** function try to declare before the function declaration. That might help.